# Distinguish between app opens from Launcher and opens from Google Play?

Tags: android, android-intent, google-play

For campaign metric purposes, I'd like to be able to distinguish between an open from the "Open" button on an app's Google Play page and an open from someone's launcher. (Not talking about fresh installs, that's easy enough.)

Nothing in that Intent (from Google Play) looks unique to me, but perhaps I'm missing something.